# Prove that if $f:\Bbb C\rightarrow C$ is a complex function whose components are of class $C^1$ then $f$ is differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, cauchy-riemann-equations

If $f:\Bbb C\rightarrow\Bbb C$ is a complex function then there exist two real scalar function $u,v:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ such that
$$
f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i
$$
for any $(x+yi)\in\Bbb C$. Now for the uniqueness of the limit if $f$ is derivable then the Cauchy-Riemann idetities
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
$$
hold. Conversely if the functions $u$ and $v$ are of class $C^1$ then it is possibile to show that $f$ is derivable but untortunately I was not able to show this: in particular I tried to prove the statement using the following argumentations

[image]

but unfortunately I was not able to prove that
$$
f(z+h)-f(z)=\Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}i\Big)(h_1+h_2i)+|h|\psi(h)
$$
moreover I tried to prove the above identity using the mean value theorem for which there exist $\xi_h,\eta_h\in\Bbb R^2$ such that
$$
u(x+h_1,x+h_2)-u(x,y)=Du(\xi_h)\cdot h\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,v(x+h_1,y+h_2)-v(x,y)=Dv(\eta_h)\cdot h
$$
and so such that
$$
f\big((x+yi)-(h_1+h_2i)\big)-f\big(x+yi\big)=\\
\Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\xi_h)\cdot h_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\xi_h)\cdot h_2\Big)+\Big(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(\eta_h)\cdot h_1+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(\eta_h)\cdot h_2\Big)i
$$
but I was not able to proceed further. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have using Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}h_1 + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}h_2\right) + i \left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}h_1 + \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}h_2\right) &= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\right)h_1 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right)h_2\\
&= \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)h_1 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)h_2\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)(h_1+ih_2)
\end{aligned}$$

for the first term. And then just set $\psi(h) = \psi_1(h) + i \psi_2(h)$.

Comment: So I am sure that
$$
f\big((x+iy)+(h_1+h_2i)\big)-f\big(x+yi)=\left(\frac{∂ u}{\partial x}(\xi_h)\cdot h_1 + \frac{∂ u}{∂ y}(\xi_h)\cdot h_2\right) + i \left(\frac{∂ v}{\partial x}(\eta_h)\cdot h_1 + \frac{∂ v}{∂ y}(\eta_h)\cdot h_2\right)=\left(\frac{∂ u}{∂ x}(\xi_h) + i\frac{∂ v}{∂ x}(\eta_h)\right)h_1 + \left(\frac{∂ u}{∂ y}(\xi_h) + i\frac{∂ v}{∂ y}(\eta_h)\right)h_2=\left(\frac{∂ u}{∂ x}(\xi_h) - i\frac{∂ u}{∂ y}(\eta_h)\right)h_1 + \left(\frac{∂ u}{∂ y}(\xi_h) + i\frac{∂ u}{∂ x}(\eta_h)\right)h_2
$$

Comment: but unfortunately I am not sure that
$$
\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\xi_h) - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\eta_h)\right)h_1 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(\xi_h) + i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(\eta_h)\right)h_2=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)(\xi_h)\cdot h_1 + \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} + i\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)(\xi_h)\cdot h_2\\
=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} - i\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)(\xi_h)\cdot(h_1+ih_2)
$$ So could you explain this to me?

Comment: The problem is that I have not understand why $$u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}h_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}h_2+|h|\cdot\psi_1(h)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,v(x+h_1,y+h_2)-v(x,y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}h_1+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}h_2+|h|\cdot\psi_2(h)$$ because I say that a function $f:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is differentiable if there exist a $1$ by $2$ matrix B such that $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)+B\cdot h}{|h|}=0$$ for any $a\in\Bbb R^2$ and so I have to prove the statement using the mean value theorem but it seems it does not work.

Comment: So could you clarify this, please?

Comment: I don't understand where all those $\eta_k, \xi_k$ are coming from???? Just sum up the first equation of the image with the second multiplied by $i$ and use Cauchy Riemann. It's pretty simple.

Comment: I defined $\eta_h$ and $\xi_h$ in the question using the mean value theorem.

Comment: You don't need that!!! Your initial question is *i was not able to prove $
f(z+h)-f(z)=\Big(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}i\Big)(h_1+h_2i)+|h|\psi(h)
$*. My answer is precisely answering that and uses the notation of the theorem in the image that you copied. You're messing up things with an additional question. Try to separate things! Or raise another question if you need it!

Comment: Okay, you are right: indeed I upvoted your question. But unfortunately I just not able to understand the identities $$u(x+h_1,y+h_2)-u(x,y)=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}h_1+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}h_2+|h|\cdot\psi_1(h)\,\,\,\text{and}\,\,\,v(x+h_1,y+h_2)-v(x,y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}h_1+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}h_2+|h|\cdot\psi_2(h)$$
because this is not my definition of differentiability. Anyway I think I will accept your answer and so I ansk a specific question about the definition of differentiability.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your assistance!!!

Comment: I don't know what's your definition of differentiability, but I imagine that proving that it is equivalent to the one of the given theorem would be pretty simple.

Comment: I put my definition above in the comment: read above.

Comment: Just write $\psi(h) = \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)+B\cdot h}{|h|}$... and you're done to prove the equivalence of the two definitions. By the way *the trick* of this notation is useful in many cases and should be remembered.

Comment: Okay, pheraps I understood. Well we know that the columns of $B$ are directional derivatives of $f$ along the axes and so $$B\cdot h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m\Rightarrow f(x+a)-f(x)+B\cdot     h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m+f(x+a)-f(x)\Rightarrow f(x+a)-f(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m+f(x+1)-f(x)-B\cdot h=f(x+a)-f(x)+\psi(h)\cdot |h|$$ right?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't prove it without assuming Cauchy-Riemman identity. The canonical example is $$f(z) = \bar{z}.$$
In this case $u(x,y)=x$ and $v(x,y)=-y$, so both $u,v$ are even of $C^\infty$ class. But $f$ is not differentiable in the complex sense.

Comment: I know this: indeed the theorem 2.4 assumes that the Cauchy-Riemann identities holds!!!

Comment: So can you prove it using the mean value theorem, please?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro So what is the question really? Do you just need more explanation about theorem 2.4?

Comment: Yes, I think I said this celarly: indeed I think I **clearly** said that I was not able to prove the indicated identity in the theorem.

Comment: I just tried to prove the teorem using the mean value theorem but unfortuantely $\xi_h$ and $\eta_h$ are generally different and when I use the Cauchy-Riemann condition this is a problem to obtain the identity  that I was not able to prove.

Comment: So could you help me, please?

Comment: Well I say that a function $f:\Bbb R^m\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ is differentiable if there is a $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that  $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B\cdot h}{|h|}=0$$ So could you show me how using this definition is possible to prove the theorem 2.4?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Consider a function 
$$\phi(h) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Bh}{|h|} & |h| \neq 0 \\
            0 & \quad h = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
Then $\phi(h)\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Conversely, having any such $\phi$ (that is arbitrary $\phi$ such that $\phi(h)\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$)you can recover $B$ as
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|h|\phi(h)-f(a+h)+f(a)}{h}$$
Here $h$ is treated as complex number thus you can divide by $h$

Comment: I messed up the signs in the above limit, but the idea stays the same

Comment: Okay, but I do not understand why $$f(a+h)-f(a)=B\cdot h+\phi(h)$$ could you show this? Forgive my confusion.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro
$$f(a+h) - f(a) = Bh + |h|\phi(h)$$
It follows from the definition of $\phi$ that I gave above

Comment: Okay, pheraps I understood. Well we know that the columns of $B$ are directional derivatives of $f$ along the axes and so $$B\cdot h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m\Rightarrow f(x+a)-f(x)+B\cdot     h=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m+f(x+a)-f(x)\Rightarrow f(x+a)-f(x)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}h^1+\dots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_m}h^m+f(x+1)-f(x)-B\cdot h=f(x+a)-f(x)+\psi(h)\cdot |h|$$ right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro
I guess, you messed a little bit in the above formula. As mathcounterexamples.net and I aresaying, the only thing is quite classical trick to use the equivalent notion of differentiability. That is the one with the existance of $\phi$ which vanishes as vanishes $h$.

Comment: Okay, anyway now it is clear. Thanks very much for your assistance!!!

Comment: You are welcome